# How to fully customize Radio button in android

Tags: java, android, mobile, radio-button

i'm trying to create fully customize radio button in my app (android).
i have 3 radio button that helps the user pick size, this is why each radio button is in different size (L,M,S). i have one picture i want to be shown in each radio button in different size. when the user pick the relevant size it should change the background of it.
i'm having very hard time with it and running in with lots of problems...
this is the Radio group (i tried different methods in each button to check what is right)
*this is inside a relative layout

```
<RadioGroup
        android:id="@+id/pizzaSizeRadioGroup"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="32dp"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_centerVertical="true"
        android:orientation="horizontal" >

        <RadioButton
            android:id="@+id/Largesize"
            android:layout_width="30dp"
            android:layout_height="30dp"
            android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
            android:adjustViewBounds="true"
            android:button="@drawable/size_selector"
            android:contentDescription="@string/largesize"
            android:padding="1dp"
            android:scaleType="fitCenter" />

        <RadioButton
            android:id="@+id/Mediumsize"
            android:layout_width="26dp"
            android:layout_height="26dp"
            android:adjustViewBounds="true"
            android:background="@drawable/size_selector"
            android:contentDescription="@string/mediumsize"
            android:padding="3dp"
            android:scaleType="fitCenter" />

        <RadioButton
            android:id="@+id/Smallsize"
            android:layout_width="24dp"
            android:layout_height="24dp"
            android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
            android:adjustViewBounds="true"
            android:button="@drawable/size_selector"
            android:contentDescription="@string/smallsize"
            android:padding="2dp"
            android:scaleType="fitCenter" />

    </RadioGroup>
```

and i built a selector

```
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" >
<item
    android:drawable="@drawable/size_select"
    android:state_checked="true"
    android:state_pressed="true" />
<item
    android:drawable="@drawable/size_select"
    android:state_pressed="true" />
<item
    android:drawable="@drawable/size_select"
    android:state_checked="true" />
<item
    android:drawable="@drawable/size_unselect" />
</selector>
```

and XML objects - size_select

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<layer-list xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" >
<item android:drawable="@drawable/pizzasize">
<shape android:shape="rectangle" >
    <corners
        android:radius="5dp" />
    <solid
        android:color="#A9D0F5" />
</shape>
</item>
</layer-list>
```

and size_unselect

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<layer-list xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" >
<item android:drawable="@drawable/pizzasize">
<shape android:shape="rectangle" >
<corners
    android:radius="5dp" />
<solid
    android:color="#FFFFFF" />
</shape>
</item>
</layer-list>
```

[image: L,M,S]

this is what i get (left is L then M and then S)

Comment: simply create one layout with three button to it and size what u want.. when user select specific button set it background along with other information what u want.

Comment: not quite understand... anyone else?